# Retrieving a list of Grails composite id properties?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

How can I retrieve a list of Grails composite id properties?

I have tried the following but the id property is returning a Long:

**Domain**

```
class Domain implements Serializable {
    String field1
    String field2

    static mapping = {
        id composite: ['field1', 'field2']
    }
}
```

**Test**

```
def d = DefaultGrailsDomainClass(Domain.class)
assert(d.identifier.type == java.lang.Long)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After deep diving [GORM](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/5.%20Object%20Relational%20Mapping%20%28GORM%29.html) I found the solution:

```
GrailsDomainBinder.getMapping(Domain).identity.propertyNames
```